# Solution for JsonMappingException: lazily initialize a collection without using @Jsonignore

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jpa, jackson

I need to response JSON as output. But It shows the exception

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.sublime.np.entity.User.roles, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.sublime.np.entity.Question["user"]->com.sublime.np.entity.User["roles"])
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:218)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:183)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.SerializerBase.wrapAndThrow(SerializerBase.java:140)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:158)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:446)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.StdContainerSerializers$IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(StdContainerSerializers.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.StdContainerSerializers$IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(StdContainerSerializers.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:86)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:610)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:256)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1613)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:209)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:143)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:89)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:193)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
```

I used so many relationship among the entities. 
My Qustion entity looks like,

```
@Entity
public class Question {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Size(min=5, message = "Title must be at least 5 characters !" )
    private String title;

    @Size(min=20, message = "Description must be at least 20 characters !" )
    private String description;

    private int upVote;

    private int downVote;

    @Column(name = "published_date")
    private Date publishedDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")

    private User user;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="question", cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private List<Answer> answers;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="question", cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE) 
    private List<Comment> comments;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="tag_id")
    private Tag tag;
```

When i use @JsonIgnore  annotation, it works. But From my json field which are in relationship disappear.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="question", cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JsonIgnore  
    private List<Answer> answers;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="question", cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JsonIgnore  
    private List<Comment> comments;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="tag_id")
    @JsonIgnore  
    private Tag tag;
```

JSON after using @JsonIgnore,

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "ABC",
    "description": "ABC",
    "upVote": 0,
    "downVote": 0,
    "publishedDate": 1433436068000
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "SQL Exception",
    "description": "ABC",
    "upVote": 0,
    "downVote": 0,
    "publishedDate": 1433436068000
  }
]
```

My Controller,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "getquestion", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Question> getQuestion() {
        List<Question> questions = questionService.getAll();
        return questions;
}
```

So, I need json with all the fields of entity. How can i get that ? any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using spring, look into OpenSessionInViewFilter http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html or you can make your @OneToMany fetch EAGER https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html

More reading:
http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/09/26/lazy-loading-in-hibernate/

Comment: If i use EAGER, it becomes to nested !  For example, Question contains user, user contains that question ..........

Comment: Yes, that would be the direct serialization of the structure showed.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Question have list of answer , list of comment, single tag , single user 
When i get question list , each question should be with its list of answer , comment , tag and user .... not nester

Comment: Not sure I get it.  Can you provide samples in your question of the output you get and how you want it?

Comment: Switching to EAGER is a terrible idea.  There is a reason LAZY is an option.  Bogging down queries by switching a collection to be EAGERly fetched will most likely hinder performance

Comment: Eager fetching is not unilaterally a "terrible idea".  Hibernate will implement this in one query while using `OpenSessionInViewFilter` will lead to N+1 queries.  There's a reason I linked to an article describing lazy loading in hibernate...